# how to call a swift function with JS?

Tags: swift, webkit, swift4, wkwebview

I should call a swift function with JS in wkwebview, but unfortunately I did not find a solution to this problem.

The solution I've tried so far, on the JS page, gave the `webkit` and the `window.webkit` commands undefined

`window.webkit.messageHandlers.userLogin.postMessage();
webkit.messageHandlers.userLogin.postMessage();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a message handler to intercept this call. Firstly you will need to conform to `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol. It will require you to implement `func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)` method, this method is where you handle the calls from your JS page. 
To tell your `WKWebView` that you can intercept JS calls. You will need to add this message handler as a configuration to your webView object when you initialise it using   `WKWebView(frame: <your frame>, configuration: <your configs>)`